# Matching array to a string in Javascript (NodeJS + EJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, foreach, ejs

*edited*

Function in the controller:

```
async postShow(req, res, next) {
        let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id).populate({
            path: 'reviews',
            options: { sort: { '_id': -1 } },
            populate: {
                path: 'author',
                model: 'User'
            }
        });
        let users = await User.find().exec();

        res.render('posts/show', { post, users });
```

going into the show.ejs page:

```
 <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
                        <% console.log(user) %>
                    <% }) %>
```

this will return the following (from mongoDB) :

```
  { image: { secure_url: '/images/default-profile.jpg' },
    _id: 5d68ea449ee71014067986e2,
    username: 'john',
    email: 'John@john.com',
    __v: 0 },
  { image: { secure_url: '/images/default-profile.jpg' },
    _id: 5d68ef0e3e133417dcc60c64,
    username: 'Tom',
    email: 'mail@mail.com',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Now <% post.author %> will return the post author's id like 5d68ef0e3e133417dcc60c64

Thing is, In the ejs template i want to match post.author to user._id and if they match i want it to return user.username of the specific user that was matched.
I hope it's a bit more clear now.
Thanks again

Comment: 1. No, the log is not an array. Each iteration of the loop simply prints a string.
2. Please post your data (original array of posts and users) so we can help you with some code.

Comment: I've edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find): The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

```
var found = users.find(function(user) {
  return user._id == post.author;
});
```

This will return the user who's `_id` property matches the `post.author` value

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vorp9g85/)

Comment: I think it should be `return user._id == post.author._id` assuming that author is the name. Or `return user == post.author` but this I am not sure if it works in JS

Comment: @noname the question says: console.log(post.author)  will return a string if it's not in the forEach loop "bye1" so it seems the author property is that string

Comment: Sorry it won't help since i'm trying to access it on the front end via EJS template, and users.find afaik won't work .   p.s i have edited the post with more details

Comment: Can't you just do it before your render and pass it through to the front end?

Comment: @BrettGregson yeah right, but in my understanding author mean 'a string' not string which is 'id' and also because he mentioned he using mongodb so I can assume author want to compare `user._id` with `post.author._id`

Comment: i've tried that but i'm getting undefined on the return value of 'found' @BrettGregson